# Unable to integrate ZXingObjC in a iOS Swift Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, zxing

Im working on an iOS project, which shows the customer number in a barcode. I had installed the framework `ZXingObjC` with CocoaPods, described in [GitHub](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC).

I can compile my Project without errors. I can also use the classes of `ZXingObjC` in my Objective-C classes, without errors. After than, I have added the import Command `#import <ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC.h>` to my bridging header file, like my other custom objective-c classes, without compile errors. (I had testet the header file by destroying some import statements and got the expected file not found exception.)

But now, I can't use any class of `ZXingObjC` in my swift classes. I only got the following compile error: `Use of undeclared type '...'`. The Xcode autocomplete is not working, too.

e.g.

```
var test : ZXMultiFormatWriter?
>> Use of undeclared type 'ZXMultiFormatWriter'
```

I tried:

- setup new project, same issue
- checked header search path: `$(SRCROOT)/Pods/Headers/Public/Adjust`
- reinstalled the ZXingObjC framework
- checked build settings: `Enable Modules: YES`
- checked build settings: `Other Linker Flags: $(inherited) -ObjC
  -framework "ZXingObjC"`
- checked linked binaries in the build phases: framework is added
- checked import statement in the bridging header file (`#import
  <ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC.h>` and `#import "ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC.h"` -- no
  difference)
- Windows style: restarting Xcode and Mac ;-)

I'm using:

- Xcode: 6.3.2
- CocoaPods: 0.37.2
- Project Deployment target: iOS 8.0
- SDK: 8.3

Does anyone know the problem? Can anyone help?
How can I make the ZXingObjC framework available in swift?

Comment: At the Other Linker Flags, I have $(inherited) -ObjC -l"Pods-ZXingObjC" -framework "AVFoundation" -framework "CoreGraphics" -framework "CoreMedia" -framework "CoreVideo" -framework "ImageIO" -framework "QuartzCore" and works well.

Answer (score 5):

Actually it is an easy issue:

Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'ZXingObjC', '~> 3.1'
```

So, on terminal:

```
cd workspace
pod install
```

Then, once opened project on Xcode, you have to edit bridging-header adding ZXingObj:

```
#import <ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC.h>
```

Finally, in your swift classes that uses ZXingObjC, you have to import ZXingObjC.

```
import ZXingObjC

class ZXingObjCWrapper {

    func encode() {
       let writer = ZXMultiFormatWriter.writer()        
       ....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The rest of the code for when you need to set an UIImage with this bar code:

```
func generateDataMatrixQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    do {
        let writer = ZXMultiFormatWriter()
        let hints = ZXEncodeHints() as ZXEncodeHints
        let result = try writer.encode(string, format: kBarcodeFormatDataMatrix, width: 1000, height: 1000, hints: hints)

        if let imageRef = ZXImage.init(matrix: result) {
            if let image = imageRef.cgimage {
                return UIImage.init(cgImage: image)
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The header search path was not correct in my project. The right values are:

```
$(inherited)
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/ZXingObjC"
```

The second and third lines were not added by installation with CocoaPods.

**EDIT:** The installed framework have to be added to "Embedded Binaries" in General tab of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything on this page to add ZXingObjC as a Pod.  My goal was to generate an Aztec barcode.

I checked my Header Search Path.  As Reddas said, I had to manually add "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/ZXingObjC".  I also added ZXingObjC as an Embedded Binary (in the General Tab).

I checked my bridging file & all was good.  I checked my view controllers where I wanted to generate the barcode.  The *import ZXingObjC* was there.

No compile errors.  But I can't declare a variable of ZXingObjC.

No luck.  Any more suggestions?

**EDIT** - I went into the Targets, Build Settings and searched for Header Search Paths.  I added in BOTH "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/**Public**/ZXingObjC" and "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/**Private**/ZXingObjC"

This seemed to unclog whatever broke.  It works now.  Strangely, I can now even delete those entries and it works.